# How to stop text from being highlighted after appending a row to a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending a row to a table using jQuery. My code looks like:

```
var tbody = $("#properties tbody");
tbody.empty();

tbody.append(
    "<tr>" + 
    "<td class='first'>State</td>" +        
    "<td>" + element.state + "</td>" + 
    "</tr>"
    );   

tbody.append(
    "<tr>" + 
    "<td>Probability</td>" +        
    "<td>" + element.prob.toFixed(6) + "</td>" + 
    "</tr>"
    );
```

The problem is that, after doing this, the text in the table is highlighted. How can I stop that from happening?

Here is a JSFiddle reproducing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pzjeavwo/

Thanks!

Comment: I just ran your code and after the row was appended, it was NOT highlighted, which leads me to believe that something else is causing this.  Do you have any other javascript or CSS?

Comment: It doesn't get highlighted in firefox, but it does in chrome for some reason.

Comment: I ran your code in Chrome and it does not get highlighted.  Do you have any other javascript or CSS?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes. Here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/pzjeavwo/

Click on the canvas and you'll see the problem.

Comment: I checked your fiddle and the table row is not highlighted upon creation.  However, if, after creating the row, I double-click, it will be highlighted - but that is true for any html content that you double-click on any web page.  I am using Chrome Version 38.0.2125.104 m.

Comment: I see. The double click is causing the highlight. If you post an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Posted an aswer - thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your fiddle and the table row is not highlighted upon creation. However, if, after creating the row, I double-click, it will be highlighted - but that is true for any html content that you double-click on any web page, so it looks like your code is working fine!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following CSS to the element whose text is being highlighted.

```
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

So it may looking something like this in your css code

```
.first {
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

user-select disables highlighting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: This works, but I don't want to stop user highlighting.

Comment: This disables all user highlighting on anything with the 'first' class, which isn't exactly needed.  It is always best to understand the problem first - and then try to solve it - rather than piling 'quick-fix' code on top of everything.  In time your solution will become completely unmanageable and you'll get all kinds of unexpected results.